# Move my carousel to the other side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, carousel

I have made a carousel and now I need to move it to the other side(instead to move to the left should move to the right). Is a really simple code based on a list. 
Check this site to understand my idea: http://diningconcepts.com/
You can see there how if you press the arrow the carousel start to move to the other side :)

Well I didnt add the arrows yet but my question is if you can make the carousel move from left to right (inverse to the current one)

Thanks in advance

Here my code

```js
$(function() {
  var list = $('ul');
  var perro = $('.perro');
  
  function onAnimate() {  
    $('ul li:first-child').appendTo('ul');
    $('ul li:last-child').css('margin-Left', 0);
      
    move();
  }
  
  function move() {
    $('ul li:first-child')
        .animate({ marginLeft: -124  }, 1500, onAnimate);
  }
  
  list.find('li:even').addClass('even');
  list.find('li:odd').addClass('odd');
  
  list.on('mouseenter', 'li', function() {
    $('ul li:first-child').stop();
  });
  
  list.on('mouseleave', move);
  
  move();
});
```

```css
div { width:1080px;overflow:hidden; }
ul { list-style-type:none;width:10000px;margin:0;padding:0; }
li { height:400px;width:108px;float:left;text-align:center;margin:0;padding:0; }
.even {background: #ccc}
.odd {background: #4e4e4e;color:#fff;}

#tomas {
 width: 600px;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
<link href="carutomstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="carujava.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="new-carousel">
    <ul>
        <li class="perro">Item #1</li>
        <li class="perro">Item #2</li>
        <li class="perro">Item #3</li>
        <li class="perro">Item #4</li>
        <li class="perro">Item #5</li>
        <li class="perro">Item #6</li>
        <li class="perro">Item #7</li>
        <li class="perro">Item #8</li>
        <li class="perro">Item #9</li>
        <li class="perro">Item #10</li>
        <li class="perro">Item #11</li>
        <li class="perro">Item #12</li>
    </ul>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Any idea about how should be the new function?

Comment: move other side? when and on what basis!! Its moving itself now to left!! when you wanna move it right?

Comment: Other side?  What does that even mean?  Other side of what?  Other side of the screen `(margin right)` instead of `(margin left)` ?

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for you quickly reply... I have edited my post... The idea is instead to move from right to left, move from left to right

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like : instead of `left to right` change it `right to left` and animation `-124` to `+124`

**For Example**

```js
$(function() {
  var list = $('ul');
  var perro = $('.perro');
  
  function onAnimate() {  
    $('ul li:first-child').appendTo('ul');
    $('ul li:last-child').css('margin-Right', 0);
      
    move();
  }
  
  function move() {
    $('ul li:first-child')
        .animate({ marginRight: 124  }, 1500, onAnimate);
  }
  
  list.find('li:even').addClass('even');
  list.find('li:odd').addClass('odd');
  
  list.on('mouseenter', 'li', function() {
    $('ul li:first-child').stop();
  });
  
  list.on('mouseleave', move);
  
  move();
});
```

```css
div#new-carousel { width:1080px;overflow:hidden; }
ul { list-style-type:none;width:10000px;margin:0;padding:0; }
li { height:400px;width:108px;float:left;text-align:center;margin:0;padding:0; }
.even {background: #ccc}
.odd {background: #4e4e4e;color:#fff;}

#tomas {
 width: 600px;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
<link href="carutomstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="carujava.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="new-carousel">
    <ul>
        <li class="perro">Item #1</li>
        <li class="perro">Item #2</li>
        <li class="perro">Item #3</li>
        <li class="perro">Item #4</li>
        <li class="perro">Item #5</li>
        <li class="perro">Item #6</li>
        <li class="perro">Item #7</li>
        <li class="perro">Item #8</li>
        <li class="perro">Item #9</li>
        <li class="perro">Item #10</li>
        <li class="perro">Item #11</li>
        <li class="perro">Item #12</li>
    </ul>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Bhavin, thanks but as you see when you run the snipet, it works really weird, we are missing something

Answer (score 0):

You need to change 'ul' margin in style

```
ul { 
    margin-left:-108px;
}
```

Change script function

```
$(function() {
     var list = $('ul');
     var perro = $('.perro');

     function onAnimate() {     
          $('ul li:first-child').css('margin-Left', 0);
          $('ul li:last-child').prependTo('ul');

          move();
      }

      function move() {
           $('ul li:first-child')
           .animate({ marginLeft: 108  }, 1500, onAnimate);
      }

      list.find('li:even').addClass('even');
      list.find('li:odd').addClass('odd');

      list.on('mouseenter', 'li', function() {
          $('ul li:first-child').stop();
      });

      list.on('mouseleave', move);

      move();
 });
```

Comment: Hi man, looks like now it works properly but how can I avoid the  whit space at the beginning?

Comment: Just add this css to remove beginning space  html,body{margin:0,padding:0}